# Никак не справлюсь с FluentSelect в Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, fluent-interface

Как можно выделить нужное значение во FluentSelect путем сравнения из Content.Role?

```
<FluentStack Orientation="Orientation.Vertical">
    <FluentTextField Style="width:100%" @bind-Value="@Content.UserName" Placeholder="Имя">Имя:</FluentTextField>
    <FluentTextArea Style="width:100%" Rows="6" @bind-Value="@Content.Password" Placeholder="Пароль">Пароль:</FluentTextArea>
    <FluentSelect Items="@SeverityOptionList"
                  @bind-Value="@SelectedValue"
                  TOption="Option<Role?>"
                  OptionText="@(p => p.Text.ToString())"
                  OptionValue="@(p => p.Value.ToString())">
    </FluentSelect>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public UserAccount Content { get; set; } = default!;
    string? SelectedValue;

    IEnumerable<Option<Role?>> SeverityOptionList =
    Enum.GetValues(typeof(Role))
    .Cast<Role?>()
    .Select(x => new Option<Role?> { Value = x!.Value, Text = x.Value });
}
```

Знаю как сделать с обычным select.

```
<select @bind="@SelectedValue" class="form-control">
@if (Content != null)
{
    @foreach (var cnt in SeverityOptionList)
    {
        if (cnt.Text == Content.Role)
        {
            <option value="@cnt.Value" selected>@cnt.Text</option>
        }
        else
        {
            <option value="@cnt.Value">@cnt.Text</option>
        }
    }
}
```